# Upgraded site from 3.5 to 4.0 - Getting an error

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis, .net-4.0

I figure there's something in the web.config I need to switch?

[A]System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingAuthenticationServiceSection cannot be cast to [B]System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingAuthenticationServiceSection. Type A originates from 'System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' in the context 'Default' at location 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Extensions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.Extensions.dll'. Type B originates from 'System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' in the context 'Default' at location 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Extensions\3.5.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.Extensions.dll'.

Comment: Also, this is hosted on GoDaddy, so I can not change anything in the GAC

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably have a stray reference to System.Web.Extensions v3.5 somewhere in Web.config.
(most likely in `<configSections>`)

Remove or replace it.

Comment: Yeah, checked that out and tried to replace it to 4.0.  No luck

Comment: Does `3.5` appear anywhere in Web.config?

Comment: I should replace all instances of 3.5 with 4.0 in web.config and see what happens?

Comment: Check what it each one is referring to first, but, probably, yes.

Comment: I just replaced them all, thought it was only the web.extensions one.  Thanks for your help.